# @using in razor page with new namespace not work on azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

On my computer and visual studio 2017.
When I add a html helper with a new namespace and import this in my ViewImports and run there are no error message, and I can use the HtmlHelper.
But when I publish with VSTS on azure, there are an error message :

```
    One or more compilation failures occurred:
 /Views/_ViewImports.cshtml(7,12): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'TagHelpers' does not exist in the namespace 'Anna' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

My code for helper:

```
namespace Anna.TagHelpers
{
    public static class IsActiveHelpersExtension
    {
        public static HtmlString IsActive(this IHtmlHelper helper, int nbAppels, int currentNbAppel)
        {
            if (nbAppels == currentNbAppel)
                return new HtmlString("class=\"active\"");
            else
                return new HtmlString(string.Empty);
        }
    }
}
```

My ViewImports:

```
@using Anna
@using Anna.Models
@using Anna.Models.AccountViewModels
@using Anna.Models.ManageViewModels
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html
@using Anna.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.JavaScriptSnippet JavaScriptSnippet
```

I don't understand what is the different on my computer and azure app service.

Comment: If it's in the same project, it could be that an old DLL is stuck on the App Service or it was not deployed. Could you try deploying to a new app service instance to test if that helps?

Comment: I have the same Anna.exe in wwwroot and wwwroot/refs directory, I have delete this and redeploy with kudu, that work now. Very Thanks.